# Exception logged in Log4j2 log file is in Unix format

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have a log4j2.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">E:/MLM/MyDomain/servers/MyAppSrv01/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/MLMServices.log" filePattern="${log-path}/MyServices-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] [%-5level] - %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
       </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is used for my application deployed on WebLogic 12.2.1 on Windows Server. When I try to log an exception stack trace like this:

```
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.catching(exception);
}
```

Or like this:

```
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.fatal("", exception);
}
```

The resulting line in the log file, when I use Notepad to see, will look like this:

14/Mar/2016 14:31:21,344 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - TestWS: catching
weblogic.management.NoAccessRuntimeException: Access to sensitive attribute in clear text is not allowed due to the setting of ClearTextCredentialAccessEnabled attribute in SecurityConfigurationMBean. Attr: CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase, MBean name: com.bea:Name=MLMAppSrv01,Type=Server
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.checkGetSecurity(SecurityInterceptor.java:590) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.management.mbeanservers.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:293) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.management.mbeanservers.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$17.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:466) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:464) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.MBeanCICInterceptor.getAttribute(MBeanCICInterceptor.java:139) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.management.mbeanservers.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$17.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:466) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:464) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.PartitionJMXInterceptor.getAttribute(PartitionJMXInterceptor.java:303) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.management.mbeanservers.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$17.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:466) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:464) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.getAttribute(CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.java:177) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.management.mbeanservers.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:283) ~[com.bea.core.management.jmx.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at com.test.TestWS.webservicemethod4(TestWS.java:132) [_wl_cls_gen.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460) [org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334) [org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) [org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:?]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3650) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.0]
14/Mar/2016 14:31:21,344 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - TestWS: webservicemethod4 1

This is because it is in Unix format rather than Windows format (it is missing the carriage return character).

How can I make each line of the stack trace ending with carriage return and newline "\r\n" so that I can view it in Notepad? We only have Notepad on the server, so viewing exception stack trace on the server can be very difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: You run code on Windows server?

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable ANSI escape sequences:

ANSI Styling on Windows

ANSI escape sequences are supported natively on many platforms but are not by default on Windows. To enable ANSI support simply add the [Jansi MVN and Jar Download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11) jar to your application and Log4j will automatically make use of it when writing to the console.

Comment: Hi, is the link that you provided valid? I keep getting 504 timeout. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that this page is down, I've updated the link

Comment: Hi jonbondani, I downloaded jansi-1.11.jar, and put it in WEB-INF\lib of my WAR file, where the log4j2 jar files are. But when I deployed and tested, the exception stack trace are still not in in Windows format. Don't we need to configure Log4j2 to let it know about this jar file?

Comment: Hi, the jansi lib must be located at jre/lib/ext or in your classpath.

Comment: If it is in WEB-INF\lib, wouldn't that be in the classpath? All jar files, including those for log4j2 ones, are in this folder and they are all automatically loaded.

Comment: If you are using eclipse to generate the war, you need to put them in the Build path, otherwise eclipse won't use them to build and generate the package.

Comment: I am using ant to build the war file. The jar file is indeed in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war file. Maybe it has to be in WEB-INF/lib/ext/ folder instead?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to move it to that folder

Comment: I put the jar file in WEB-INF\lib\ext, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I tried this on a stand alone program. I have log4j-core-2.5.jar, log4j-api-2.5.jar, and jansi-1.11.jar in the classpath. The exception stack trace is still without the carriage return ("\r").